# Toggle between Relative to Fixed position on scrpll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-position

I believe that it's a very small tweak to make it work...

I need to switch between fixed to relative position.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pWHx)

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
      ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) ? ($('.me').addClass('fixed')) : ($('.me').removeClass('fixed'))
    };
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="me">123</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Where is the exact bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me.....

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) ? $('.me').addClass('fixed') : $('.me').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

may be some brackets missing... and if you want to put css directly with jquery use .css();

working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/2pWHx/2/)